# Scanning azure blob store container in spark java

Tags: java, azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

I need to read all the files from azure blob container into spark RDD. I am using azure HDInsight, my cluster is configured in the same storage account as that of my input directory.

Is there any java API / example for achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

It will look like regular Spark Java example, just use "wasb://" file system to reference to the blob storage container:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json("wasb://yourcontainer@yourstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/people.json");
```

More details on Java APIs are on spark web-site (click on the Java tab): https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-dataframes

Answer (score 0):

@maxiluk didn't answer the question fully. So I am going to give some more details. The example he gave will load one json file. To load a whole directory of json files you can use a wildcard like (This will load the whole container):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json("wasb://yourcontainer@yourstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/*");
```

If you want to load more than one directory, but not all, you can pass a comma separated list of them of directories: (if you want more details on this check out the [Code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/DataSource.scala))

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json("wasb://yourcontainer@yourstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/2016/10/01/*,wasb://yourcontainer@yourstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/2016/10/02/*");
```

Depending on the spark version you are using and if you have a SqlContext or just a SparkContext, you might also be able to pass in an Seq[String] of the paths and not a comma separated list.